# How to check if current drive is on a local disk (cmd)?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

To get the drive the current batch resides in is easy using

```
set batchdrive=%~d0
```

But how is it possible to check if `%batchdrive%` is on a local drive and not on a (mapped) network share?

Checking for `%SYSTEMDRIVE%` or a fixed list "C:" "D:" ... is not reliable.

Comment: `wmic LogicalDisk where (DeviceID="%~d0" AND DriveType=3) get DeviceID` (returning an error if drive is not local)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to check is if `batchdrive` is an unmapped network share (this happens if you start the batch file outside of cmd.exe, for example via double click or via a system call):

```
if "%batchdrive%" == "\\" set nshare=1
```

The second thing is to check if `batchdrive` is in the list of network shares. These are shown with `net use`, which output is similar to

```
status        local   remote              network
-------------------------------------------------------------------
OK            D:      \\computer1\share1  Microsoft Windows Network
OK            E:      \\computer1\share2  Microsoft Windows Network
disconnected  F:      \\computer2\share   Microsoft Windows Network
Command executed successfully.
```

Therefore we filter the output for all lines that looks like a disk drive with `findstr /r /c:" [A-Z]: "` and took the second part of the output via `for /f "tokens=2"`.

Complete snipped (working on WinXP and above):

```
if "%~d0" == "\\" (
   set nshare=1
) else (
   set nshare=0
   for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('net use ^| findstr /r /c:" [A-Z]: "') do (
       if "%%a" == "%~d0" set nshare=1
   )
)
```

Comments for possible issues requested :-)

Comment: Remark: this code will raise a false-positive if the *local* batch is on a network share and started with an UNC path: `\\localhost\share\local.bat` (but I'm fine with this)

Answer (score 2):

To check whether a drive (`%~d0`) is a local one, you could use a `wmic` query:

```
wmic LogicalDisk where(DeviceID="%~d0" AND DriveType=3) get Description,DeviceID,DriveType
```

Given that `%~d0` expands to the local drive `C:`, the output looks like:

> ```
> Description       DeviceID  DriveType
> Local Fixed Disk  C:        3
> ```

In case `%~d0` is a network drive `Z:`, the error output is:

> ```
> No Instance(s) Available.
> ```

Unfortunately, `wmic` does not set the `ErrorLevel` in case of no matches, but the above message is returned at the *STDERR* stream rather than the *STDOUT* stream, so we can apply redirection to discard *STDOUT* (in case the drive matches; so the `get` query is omitted as it is not used anyway) and redirect *STDERR* to *STDOUT* instead (so the error message is returned at *STDOUT* in case):

```
2>&1 > nul wmic LogicalDisk where (DeviceID="%~d0" AND DriveType=3)
```

Hence the command line returns nothing in case `%~d0` is a local drive, but something otherwise. Now let us capture the (redirected) *STDOUT* by a `for /F` loop:

```
for /F "delims=" %%L in ('
    2^>^&1 ^> nul wmic LogicalDisk where ^(DeviceID^="%~d0" AND DriveType^=3^)
') do echo Drive "%~d0" is not local!
```

So if `%~d0` points to a local drive, the body of `for /F` is not executed, but otherwise it is.

---

According to [this resource](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html), WMI and therefore the `wmic` command line tool is available since Windows XP (Prof.) onward; it was not available on Windows XP Home though. `wmic` does not require administrative privileges. The [`Win32_LogicalDisk`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173(v=vs.85).aspx) class is available since availability of WMI. Reference the following resources for more information about WMI/`wmic`: [Windows Management Instrumentation: Frequently Asked Questions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692772.aspx) and [WMIC - Take Command-line Control over WMI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I assume a typo in "returned at the STDERR stream rather than the STDERR stream".
Do you know/can you check if `LogicalDisk` is available on all systems?

Comment: WMI is available in Win2000+ and WinME+ already. You can even install it on older systems (Windows 95/98/NT 4.0) - the download was removed from MS downloads but you can find it if needed when searching for "WMI CORE 1.5".

Comment: I corrected the typo, thanks for the hint! I'm not sure whether WMI and the `wmic` command line tool both have been introduced at the same time (throughout all Windows 2000/XP editions)...

Comment: OK, I did some more checking. WMI is available in WinME/Win2000+ by default, available in 95/98/NT 4.0 by manual install.
The command line tool `wmic` is only available (and installed by default) for WinXP (Prof)+. Access rights granted you can `wmic` query other (older) PC over network but as this is about local computers the solution needs WinXP+.
The available providers depend on the system but at least with WinXP+ LogicalDisk is available.
I suggest to add this information to your answer.

Comment: I updated my answer slightly. I am sorry but I do not want to include the information you provided in my answer without stating some (preferrably Microsoft) references -- do you have such? (In addition the question does not even ask for those.) I am totally surprised that WMI was available even for MS-DOS-based Windows versions like Windows ME...

Comment: Reference for WMI (including the Win98/NT4 part): https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692772.aspx

Reference for `wmic` (including the XP Prof+ part and the query older OS part): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx

Correction to your answer: `wmic` is available with WinXP Prof, Win 2003 and newer

BTW: By checking all these references I've learned a lot of the historic WMI/`wmic` issues, too.